# General Solution + Particular solution..

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

how what the particular solution simplified to 1/3 ??

Comment: Is it possible to convert your question to TeX formatting? Few people are going to be interested in deciphering handwriting.

Comment: @ALB I have no clue on how to do that

Comment: Learning to typeset in TeX is going to be an important part both of using MSE and pursing a career in science, math, or engineering. I highly recommend learning. See https://www.latex-project.org/about/ for a basic guide.

Comment: edited question

Answer (score 0):

When your forcing term ($12e^{2t}$) is of the same form as the homogeneous part and you're trying to find a particular solution, a good idea to try is $t\times$ that, i.e. $Ate^{2t}$, which is what you've done. You say $3e^{2t}$ and $e^{2t}$ are "similar terms", which is true, However this is not what you have, you have $3te^{2t}$, and this is quite different to $e^{2t}$.

---

Response to edit:
The particular solution is given as $$\frac13(\cos3x)^2+\frac13(\sin3x)^2=\frac13(\cos^23x+\sin^23x)=\frac13$$
At the end we use the identity $\sin^2u+\cos^2u=1$.

Comment: I'm trying to do a what if situation so that I can understand more clearly what would happen if this was the case.

Comment: Ohh I see, in this case, I think Peter's answer explains this perfectly, if $x(p)=c_3e^{2t}+c_4e^{-2t}$, then the total solution would just be of the form $(c_1+c_3)e^{2t}+(c_2+c_4)e^{-2t}$, which doesn't solve the equation - so this is never the case, it is not possible

Comment: edited question

Comment: This edit changed the question you were asking, edits should be used to make small changes. I think you should change the question back to what it was, and ask a new question if you have a new question, or at least leave what was originally there as it is, and just add something